# Why does defining main() with no return type compile with no error?

Tags: c++, gcc

I was just testing this code by compiling it with GCC (`g++`);

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(int argc, char **argv){

    printf("something");

}
```

It seems to build and run fine with just a warning saying;

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'main' with no type [-Wreturn-type]
```

Though I defined `main()` with no return type and not returning any value to it.
I then decided to test the same code by compiling it with Visual C++ compiler but it efficiently threw the error:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

and the build was not successful.

I was expecting GCC to throw an error and stop compiling instead of a warning and letting it build successfully.

Why does GCC give `main()` such privilege of not letting it know its return type?

Comment: Because the standard says so.

Comment: The standard says what?

Comment: You're compiling the code with the C++ compilers, but you've tagged the question with C.  Starting with GCC 5.1.0, the C compiler would complain by default about your code because it compiles in C11 mode (strictly, `-std=gnu11`) by default.

Comment: Every program is supposed to return an exit code upon its termination, and C way of doing that is returning an `int` from `main()`. Even if you find a compiler that allows `main()` to work without a return value, it might cause problems as the program will return undefined exit code.

Comment: @NanaOsaberima: that the return type must be specified.  G++ is being (unnecessarily) nice letting it through.  See [What should `main()` return in C and C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/).

Comment: [3.6.1.5: "If control reaches the end
of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
`return 0;`"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

Comment: GCC will produce a warning `[Warning] return type defaults to 'int' [-Wreturn-type]`.

Comment: @wcochran how is that question the same as mine?

Comment: @NanaOsaberima my bad -- I was thinking no `return` statement. In C when a type is not specified, the default is `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the fact that G++ is being 'unnecessarily' nice is what i'm worried about. What else would or wouldn't it be 'unnecessarily' nice to!

Comment: @NanaOsaberima Well, you can tell it to stop being nice. Add `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

Comment: There are lots of extras in the GNU compilers.  If you don't want them, you have to turn them off explicitly.  That means `-std=c++14`, preferably with `-pedantic`, or similar for earlier standards.  Otherwise, you get GNU C++ with extensions over the standard.  (This is standard behaviour for GCC.)  You could usefully add some of the warning flags suggested by @Praetorian in his [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677292/why-does-defining-main-with-no-return-type-compile-with-no-error#comment49416287_30677292) too.

Comment: Alright! Thanks Jonathan Leffler  and Praetorian

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question (and apparently I only need one vote to do it). The [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/827263) is about the best way to define `main`; the answer correctly says it should have a return type of `int`. This question asks why gcc accepts `main` *without* an explicit return type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The program is ill-formed. Omitting the return type is not permitted by the C++ standard.

The reason the compiler doesn't treat it as a fatal error is historical. Prior to the 1999 standard, C did permit the return type of a function to be omitted; it would default to `int`. C++ is derived from C, so early (pre-standard) versions of C++ had the same rule.

In modern C++, omitting the return type is an error. The compiler is required to *diagnose* such an error, but it's not required to treat it as fatal. By printing a warning, the compiler has done its job as far as the standard is concerned.

Don't ignore warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your are using a compiler that implements some non-standard language extensions. One of them is old-style-C-like "implicit `int`" rule for function declarations. So, your function declarations implies `int` return type from the point of view of that specific compiler.

It should also be said that from the point of view of C++ language, the compiler is not required to refuse to compile invalid code or issue an "error". It is only required to issue a diagnostic message, any diagnostic message. That warning you saw is already a diagnostic message. The compiler gave you a warning that says "ISO C++ forbids..." - that is already a sufficient sign that your code is broken. After that it is completely irrelevant whether your code "compiled without an error" or not.

Anyway, if you configure your compiler to disable non-standard extensions (see `-pedantic-errors` flag and `-std` flag), the compiler will certainly refuse to compile your code.

Comment: What exactly are "standard extensions" to you? Do you mean conforming vs non-conforming extensions?